# "firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential" is undefined (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication

I've been working on my first React Native project using Firebase Auth (plain email&password only).
Signing-in, Signing-out, Resetting passwords, etc... everything is fine, but I'm stuck with one thing and I need help with deleting user.
Because deleting user is a "sensitive" request, Firebase Auth demands re-authenticating the user before actually deleting the user.
This is where I can't figure out how to do it. Even the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user) don't tell much. They literally say: "TODO(you): prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials".

**ErrorMessage** :
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential')

**My firebase.js** :

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = { //key hidden here for security reasons
    apiKey: apiKey,
    authDomain: authDomain,
    projectId: projectId,
    storageBucket: storageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: messagingSenderId,
    appId: appId,
    measurementId: measurementId
  };

const app = !firebase.apps.length
  ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : firebase.app();
  
  const db = app.firestore();
  const auth = firebase.auth();

export {db, auth};
```

**My component.js** :

```
...
import { auth } from '../firebase/firebase';
...
    const deleteUser = () => {
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        const credential = auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(userEmail,userProvidedPassword);
        user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential).then(() => {
            user.delete().then(() => {
                auth.signOut();
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.message);
            });
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what dependency you added for Firebase?

Comment: I solved this, I actually didn't even use "reauthenticateWithCredential".
I made it just simply re-sign-in and then delete it, and it works out just fine.
Thank you for the reply though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

##### You cannot delete users from the front-end React Native!

Instead, there is firebase admin SDK which allows you to delete users but it has to be done from the backend. I believe this [link to Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) will answer your questions.

Also, do check [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) if you don't have a backend and you are just relying on Firebase.

> Cloud Functions allows you to create a function in Firebase that you can call from React Native using Firebase SDK and perform delete user operation also you could watch for a collection and send notification and do more stuff!

And it is simple than it sounds!

Comment: This is false. You can delete a Firebase user from React Native front end.

Answer (score 0):

The example is kinda confusing but I figured it out. After the user is redirected from the sign-in link, the user should continue from that window. So at the browser `window.location.href` can receive a new URL from Firebase and  use it to create `credential` and keep continue from here.